# SQL Report Builder 3.0 trying to check for nulls OR a date in a date range and received filter errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I am new to report builder and I am using it with SharePoint 2010 to create a report combining several lists. I have a dataset that has a datetime field column that I need to interrogate to limit the rows pulled back to the report. I thought a filter would do the trick... however I cannot seem to figure out the proper way to pull only what I need. 
I need all rows where orderstatus is completed and date1 is empty or has been pushed out to 2015.

Example data:

```
ID  DATE1           OrderStatus
1   Empty           Completed
2   Empty           Not Started
3   12/01/2012      Completed
4   03/05/2013      Completed
5   08/21/2014      Completed
6   12/31/2014      Completed
7   01/07/2015      Completed
8   01/08/2015      Not Started
9   01/31/2015      Completed
```

In Group Properties I added the filter where OrderStatus (Text) = Completed and this works but I also need all rows with an empty date (or anything before 1960) or a date where the year is 2015 with orderstatus completed.
From the data above I expect to see in my report the following rows:
1, 7, and 9

Is there a better way to add the OR option and when I use the fx for the expression or the value I get rsfilter errors. 
Here is the first filter:

```
 Expression    OrderStatus (Text)
 Operator       =
 Value             Completed
```

Here is the second filter I added: (this filter receives errors and will not process)

```
 Expression    Date1   (Date/Time)
 Operator       =
 Value [Expr]   =(Fields!Date1.Value) < 12/01/1960 Or (Fields!Date1.Value) > 12/31/2014
```

I have tried different methods with OrElse, Xor, IsNothing, multiple Ands' etc... at the query level the row and report level filtering but still get a similar result. 
Can someone point me in the right direction to achieve my end goal? I have looked in Microsoft and their examples do not have a scenario of 1 column needing the empty and a date range included in the result set.

I have corrected the syntax errors above as directed but still have a RSFilterProcessError. I will look at other examples. the tool does not lend me to easily copy the filter code to paste here. All suggestions welcome.

Comment: I corrected the syntax and received a type error, so I modified the expression to only evaluate the < or > and took the year off so that the types would be compatible. Now I am receiving the following error..................... Failed to evaluate the FilterValue of the Grouping ‘Details1’. (rsFilterEvaluationError)

Answer (score 0):

I can see a syntax problem in these expressions:

```
Year(Fields!Date1.Value < 1960)
Year(Fields!Date1.Value = 2015)
```

You have the brackets in the wrong place. `Year()` is a function that accepts a date parameter and returns a year, which you then compare with a value.

Change them to:

```
Year(Fields!Date1.Value) < 1960
Year(Fields!Date1.Value) = 2015
```

Comment: I made the syntax changes and I receive an error on data types the err reads "The processing of the FilterExpression for the grouping "Details1" cannot be performed. Cannot compared date of types System.DateTime and System.Boolean. Please check the data type returned by the filterExpression(rsComparisonTypeError)

Comment: Your code is pretty badly messed up. What's the equals sign doing after the "or"? Remove it. Look at some more examples and copy them.

Comment: I have looked at all the examples I can find and copied from Microsoft... however they do not give a solution for the OR scenario so maybe it cannot be done in a group properties filter at least for the date fields. I may have to take it back to the row or query level to make it work. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have had some difficulty trying to fit complex statements into Report Builder's filters. What has worked for me is to set the filter as Boolean and do the expression as an iif.

Expression:
=IIF(Year(Fields!Date1.Value) < 1960 OR Year(Fields!Date1.Value) = 2015, true, false)

Type:
Boolean

Operator:
 =

Value:
True